# Export in one PDF multiple range from different sheet

Tags: excel

I have an Excel file with multiple sheets, i would like to export specific range (different for sheet 1 & sheet 2) on sheet 1 & sheet 2 on the first page of a PDF and a specific range of sheet 6 to the second page of the exported pdf.

So i would like to write a VBA macro to do the following:

- Create one pdf of 2 pages
- First page of PDF would have the specific range from Sheet 1 & Sheet 2
- Second page of PDF would have the specific range from sheet 3
- Since range are big, the zoom should be ajustable to fit.
- Save path should be selectable in a message box with overwrite support

Thanks !

I tried to write what i know :

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

 Sheets("Hypothèses").Select
    Range("Print_Area").Select
    Sheets("Composition").Select
    Range("Print_Area").Select
    Sheets("Coûts de revient").Select
    Range("Print_Area").Select

        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Array("Hypothèses", "Composition", "Coûts de revient")).Select
        Selection.ExportAsFixedFormat _
            Type:=xlTypePDF, _
            Filename:="", _
            Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
            IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
            IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
            OpenAfterPublish:=True

    Sheets("Hypothèses").Select
    Range("A1").Select

End Sub
```

Doesn't work and the split is not as needed.